# java.io.filenotfoundexception jboss project localhost

Tags: java, jboss, localhost

I've been working on web project written in jsp and running on jboss. I have problem after deployment of project. I'm getting an error after hitting `localhost:8080/Myapp : java.io.filenotfoundexception Null/easyfile.properties <Can't find easyfile.properties>`. I have this file in conf folder in my app directory. For sure I need to properly point to this file or place it somewhere in jboss installation folder but unfortunately I'm new to `Java` and 've been working with PHP but I've been assigned to client who has home site written as one jsp site with some xml. I need to change their frontend a little bit but I'm trying to set up my local environment without success.

Any help would be great.

Regards Adam

Comment: Adam - more info will be needed - show your file structure and where you're accessing easyfile.properties

Comment: post code which is accessing properties file. Since it is saying `Null` which means if you are using any Env_variable or something same, is not set properly.